# Rails 4 nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  
  resources :states do
    resources :cities do
      get 'listings'
    end
  end

end
```

I am looking to have my **GET URL**  set up like:
`../state.id/city.id/listings.id`

I am using `friendly_id` so the urls will read like:

```
../OR/Portland/2011-ford-truck
```

Comment: Looks like what you really want is a triple nested route, instead of get 'listings', try using resources :listings, this will give you "../state.id/city.id/listings.id".

Answer (score 3):

Listing is it's own model (resource) too in this case.  You will also need a `resources` for listing.  If it only has a `show` action, you can limit it like this:

```
resources :states do
  resources :cities do
    resources :listings, only: [:show]
  end
end
```